# Would Android 4.3 mount exFAT formatted external SD card automatically without requiring additional software?

Tags: external-sd, 4.3-jelly-bean, mount, exfat

Would Android 4.3 mount exFAT formatted external SD card automatically without additional software?

Comment: Do you not have the device or the SD card in reach? If you have, then why not experiment on your own? You would surely get the answer.

Comment: I think in the past this was manufacturer-specific, because exFAT is [patent encumbered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT#Restrictive_licensing_and_software_patents). I'm not sure if Google has (or has the ability to get) a generic license agreement that would apply to the OS at large, or if it's been somehow reverse engineered.

Comment: Your question is about Android 4.3 supporting exFAT formatted SD cards, and not about listing supported filesystems by 4.3 which would be broad thing to answer. That's why I edited the title to reflect the body only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exFAT support is kernel based.
open terminal and run

```
cat /proc/filesystems
```

if in the subsequent listing you see

```
.       exfat
```

your kernel supports exfat file system unless the build is skunky.
if the in the listing you see

```
nodev     exfat
```

then you don't have exfat support.
In one instance i've seen, even though the kernel may have exfat support, the rom may not, or it's "broken" in some way. As to the formatting of the card, i believe it needs to be formatted exfat and unaligned.
Else, it should mount like any other external card with one exception, the entry in your fstab for the external card. If the entry for `<type>`
is vfat, then you may have a problem. The entry should be auto or, if you know how to unpack and edit, then repack and flash your boot.img, you can specify exfat.